# Remove hashmark (#) from nginx url and redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect

I want to take a url, add a prefix as well as remove the hashmark from the url.  For example, redirect from http://localhost:8088/app1/#/hello to http://localhost:8088/apps/app1/hello.

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
  location /app1/ {
    rewrite ^([^#]*)([#])\/(.*) /apps$1$3 permanent;
  }
```

It seems to have something to do with the hashmark.  As I can go from http://localhost:8088/app1/q/hello to http://localhost:8088/apps/app1/hello with this:

```
  location /app1/ {
    rewrite ^([^q]*)([q])\/(.*) /apps$1$3 permanent;
  }
```

Is there something I need to do to handle the hashmark in a redirect?

Comment: [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664257/why-is-the-hash-part-of-the-url-not-available-on-the-server-side). It's never sent to the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. The browser doesn't send anything after `#` to the `nginx`. The `#` indicates an [URL fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) which is processed on a client only.

Comment: ...and to be clear, as a consequence, the route handling for fragments need to happen in your http://localhost:8088/app1/ javascript code. That's a subject for stackoverflow, rather than serverfault though: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=js+router